# replace jQuery function with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to replace this jQuery function with pure javascript.

```
$('#myTable span.hide').click(function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    return false;
});
```

I tried to replace it with this but it doesn't work in IE.

```
function rem(id) {
    id.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML = "<td></td>";
}
```

Here's how the table looks:

```
<tbody id="thebody">
<tr>
    <td>
       <span onclick="rem(this);" class="hide"></span>
    </td>
    //More td's here
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function rem(id) { // id may be ambiguous here, because it's the element, not an ID
    var elem = id; // current elem

    while(elem.nodeName !== "TR") { // move up to tr as long as it isn't tr yet
        elem = elem.parentNode; // if not tr yet, set elem to parent node
    }

    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem); // remove tr from parent node
}
```

Note that your HTML should include a `<table>` - a raw `<tbody>` is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the `<span>` element itself, do this:

```
function rem(el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```

If you want to remove the closest `<tr>`, then you need something like:

```
function rem(el) {
    while(el.nodeName != "TR") {
        el = el.parentNode;
    }
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function rem(id) {
    id.parentNode.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: This will remove the `td` not the `tr` element, which is what the jQuery version does.

Comment: Your code replace the TD with blank TD, my code just clean the TD contents. Whats the difference? You want to clean the td attributes too?

Comment: I think @Shef refers to his jQuery function and not his attempt to recreate the function with pure JavaScript.

Comment: @Stefan: I referred to OP's jQuery code, not mine if that's what you want to say. Correction on my first comment: I meant _"this will remove the content of `td` not the `tr` itself."_

Comment: Sorry, of course I ment that you referred to Niklas(his) jQuery function :)